# epimorphism of fppf sheaves is an fppf morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I asked this question on math.stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693471/epimorphism-of-fppf-sheaves-is-an-fppf-morphism) but didn't get an answer. Maybe someone here can help.

Suppose $0→F→G→H→0$ is an exact sequence of group schemes (over some base scheme $S$
) by which I mean that the corresponding sequence of fppf-sheaves is exact.

I read somewhere that the surjectivity of the sequence of fppf-sheaves is equivalent to the fact that the morphism $G\to H$
 is fppf (faithfully flat and locally of finite presentation).

I was able to prove one of the directions: If $G\to H$
 is fppf then the sequence of fppf-sheaves is surjective.

I'm not sure how to prove the other direction. Any help/reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: That is not correct. Consider the case that $H$ is the trivial group $S$-scheme, i.e., just $S$ as an $S$-scheme, and $F=G$ is an arbitrary group  $S$-scheme that is not necessarily flat over $S$.

Comment: The result is correct if you assume, in addition, that $F$ is flat over $S$, since then $G$ is an $F$-torsor over $H$.